# Is it possible to convert a column from string to datetime type in a SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, type-conversion

I need to query SQLite datebase table using the following SQL Statement.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Alarms 
WHERE ALARMSTATE IN (0,1,2) 
  AND ALARMPRIORITY IN (0,1,2,3,4) 
  AND ALARMGROUP IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) 
  AND DateTime(ALARMTIME) BETWEEN datetime("2012-08-02 00:00:00") 
                    AND datetime("2012-08-03 00:00:00") 
ORDER BY ALARMTIME DESC
```

ALARMTIME is of TEXT datatype.

ALARMTIME is displayed in the datagridview as follow "08/03/2012 11:52 AM". Can you use that format for checking like DateTime(ALARMTIME)?

The only problem have with this SQL Statement is that it always returns zero dataset or records. However, SQLite doesn't complain about the syntax.

Comment: I'm assuming there is data within 'Alarms' that would cause it to meet each 'AND' criteria?

Comment: @JamieKeeling, Yes, there is a lot of data in the table.

Comment: @ChrisMoutray, yes it returns whole bunch of records when I don't check for ALARMTIME. Ummmmm, ALARMTIME looks like 08/02/2012 11:41AM. Ohhhhh gosh....I think I see it now...but I want to hear from you before I jump to conclusion....:)

Comment: Actually I know very little about sqlite, it just felt like a thing to confirm/check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, SQLite doesn't have [datetime types for its columns](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
> and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
> are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
> values

The problem here is that the string you're using condition isn't a valid date/time, so it's treated as null:

```
sqlite> SELECT datetime("2012-08-3 00:00:00");

sqlite> SELECT datetime("2012-08-03 00:00:00");
2012-08-03 00:00:00
```

(Note `2012-08-03` instead of `2012-08-3`.)

In addition, make sure that the values in your `ALARMTIME` are correctly formatted too.

Comment: Bruno, I see why my SQL statement runs but not return any records. It is because of my ALARMTIME column text format. Knowing this, it only complicates my coding further.

Comment: I'm not sure about the content of your column, but if the data there is fine, the simple fact that the condition you're using is incorrect is sufficient to cause the problem for any correct value: `SELECT datetime("2012-08-02 01:00:00") BETWEEN datetime("2012-08-02 00:00:00") AND datetime("2012-08-03 00:00:00")` returns 1, whereas `SELECT datetime("2012-08-02 01:00:00") BETWEEN datetime("2012-08-02 00:00:00") AND datetime("2012-08-3 00:00:00")` returns null.